# requires changing the baseUrl on the same file

Tags: requirejs

I have the following file structure:

```
|- index.html
   vendor
    |- jquery.min.js (some libraries)
   js
    |- app.js
```

When I try to load the index.html from my browser using the following url:

```
http://localhost/~myname/WebFrontend/
```

I get the following error in `conf.js` (see the comments on conf.js).

How should I fix this problem?

---

```
// index.html
<script data-main="js/conf" src="./vendor/require.js"></script>
```

---

```
 // conf.js
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '../vendor',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'jquery.min', // it works
    }
});

require(['../js/app']); // http://localhost/~mynane/js/router.js not found
require(['./js/app']); // http://localhost/~myname/vendor/js/router.js not found
// I would like to point to http://localhost/~antoniopierro/WebFrontend/js/router.js
```

Comment: do you mean app.js is not found or do you really mean router.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure it will be possible to change the baseUrl on the same file.
And also if you load another module I don't think you can change the baseUrl.

Anyway:

1) You said jquery module is successfully load.
It is false because you don't get the error just because the `require(['../js/app']);` fails.
2) With your structure I suggest to define the `baseUrl: './'` .
In this way you will be able to access the vendor modules making `vendor/filename` and your source files making `js/filenane`.